# How to add user to www-data on CentOS?

Tags: linux, permissions, centos

I have a problem with a specific area of my website. I have a server with CentOS on it and basic knowledge of Linux systems.

The problem occurs when the folder is set to 755, but when set to 777 it's working fine. I know 777 is not secure, so I looked it up and apparntely I need to add the admin user to a group called www-data. However, when trying to do that, I'm told www-data group doesn't exist which I imagine has something to do with CentOS being a different distribution of Linux.

It might be worth noting that I already added the user admin to the 'apache' group a few days ago, I'm not sure if it's related or not...

Anyway, how can I add the user to this group on CentOS to fix this permission issue?

Thanks

Comment: To which group the folder belongs to? In Centos the httpd group is `apache` and in Ubuntu it is `www-data`

Comment: If you don't have a `www-data` group then adding the admin user to that isn't going to help. What *specifically* is the permissions problem you are having? What is the ownership information of the directory/files that have the problem?

Answer (score 9):

Add an Existing User to a Group

```
 usermod -a -G <groupname> username
```

In centOS is:

```
usermod -a -G apache username
```